Iterate through form elements returned to python
I have a form that is populated with a list of image files that the user can delete. When the form is created, a Jinja loop iterates through the list of photo files and provides a preview of the image and a checkbox so the user can select which images to remove.
{% for elem in orphans %}
     <input type="checkbox" id="op_checkbox_{{loop.index}}"></input>
     <img src="{{ITEM_IMAGE_DIR}}{{elem}}" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;  max-width:230px; max-height:50px;  width: auto;  height: auto;">
{% endfor %}


When the form is POSTed to my Python app, I need to iterate through the list of checkboxes and determine which ones are checked. A hidden input returns the number of photos.
    for i in num_items:
       form_var = "op_checkbox_" + str(i)
       if (request.form[form_var] == True):


This doesn't work, obviously. However, I've been unable to determine what would...
What I tried was using a variable as the element part of the request.form[element] What I expected was to be able to access the form elements.
I'm hoping someone has a solution. But if this isn't the correct way to do this, an alternative method for accessing an arbitrary number of form variables would also work.

You can access every element of the same name to iterate through and then give each one a value so you can identify them.
In your template.html
{% for elem in orphans %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="op_checkbox_{{loop.index}}"></input>
    <img src="{{ITEM_IMAGE_DIR}}{{elem}}" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;  max-width:230px; max-height:50px;  width: auto;  height: auto;">
{% endfor %}

In your route.py
chkbox_values = request.form.getlist('chkbox')
for i in num_items:
   form_var = "op_checkbox_" + str(i)
   if form_var in chkbox_values:
       # do something

Consider using a dictionary key or some sort of unique identifier instead of an index when assigning values to unique objects.
